# Migrating mercurial to git with \n as a part of branch name -- "fatal: Expected committer but didn't get one"

Tags: git, mercurial

We are trying to migrate mercurial repo to git with hg-fast-export.
The script crashes when we reach a branch with `\n` as a part of that branch name.
We use the mapping file and it seems that the relevant line, unlike the rest of the lines is ignored.

This is the error we are getting:

```
fatal: Expected committer but didn't get one
```

We tried the following:

1. Make sure we don't have a breaking symbol in the mapping files.
2. We ran without a mapping file.
3. Considered rename the branch in the mercurial and it seems too complicated.

Is there a workaround and what additional details can I provide?

Comment: Branch names in git cannot, as far as I know at least, have newline characters in them. As such the migration tool probably does not handle that very well. How are you doing the convertion?

Comment: using convert extension in Mercurial, you can rename branch *easy* with `--branchmap`

Comment: In my mapping file for branches, it was defined like this: "1234\n -My New Branch"="kiln/123 - My New Branch". As far as I know, the `sanitize_name` function returned a two-line name:
```
1234
 -My New Branch
```

It looks like it didn't find the match in the mapping file (I don't know why).
So after some digging in the code, I made some changes in this function ( `sanitize_name`), I change a regex to `([[ ~^:?\\\\*\r\n]|\.\.)` instead of `([[ ~^:?\\\\*]|\.\.)`. After the change, it still didn't find a match inside a mapping file but at least it was able to convert the branch name.